# Edit Large Datatable Performance Issue

Tags: c#, winforms, datatable

I have a datatable with around 100k records. Datatable has multiple columns that contains some integer values. I need to add those integer values and write it into column `Total Count` and `Common Count`. I am using following code but it taking about 10-15 seconds. How can i do this in efficient way ??

**Edited Part Start**

```
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@pudTowerList", SqlDbType.VarChar, 8000).Value = cellId;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@pudTowerCol", SqlDbType.VarChar, 8000).Value = cellIdCol;
sqlCon.Open();
SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Load(dr);
SqlCon.Close();
cmd.Dispose();
```

**Edited Part Ended**

Here i edit this datable and then bind to gridview at the end

```
 foreach (DataRow drow in dt.Rows)
   {
      int nTotalCount = 0;
      int nCommonCount = 0;
      for (int i = 2; i < nColumnCount; i++)
      {
         nTotalCount += int.Parse(drow[i].ToString());
         if (int.Parse(drow[i].ToString()) != 0)
         {
            nCommonCount += 1;
         }
      }
       drow["Total Count"] = nTotalCount; // On commenting this lines it runs fast
       drow["Common Count"] = nCommonCount; // On commenting this lines it runs fast
    }
```

Comment: But if it is readOnly.. How can i going to be edit the values

Comment: @Anirudh I am not going to insert the total count in database. This is just for showing the values in grid only. Please look at my edited question showing what i m doing in complete

Comment: From what i can understand, nTotalCount is the sum of all column values and nCommonCount is the no. of column values which is not zero. Have i understood correctly? Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Find a way to replace

```
int.Parse(drow[i].ToString());
```

with direct casting:

```
(int)drow[i];
```

If you already don't have integers in cell values, do whatever you can to have them there.

Other than that - look out for any events that might be fired as a result of column value update - maybe that is what's slowing you down.

Another idea: use SQL to calculate column values!

Comment: you mean procedure return me the calculated values

Answer (score 0):

I suggest not to perform such heavy task in c#, instead return this calculated values from sql server it self(try to manipulate this heavy data in a stored procedure) and return calculated value.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of computing in C#, you can compute this in SQL as given below:

```
SELECT Id,Col1,Col2,Col3, 
Col1+Col2+Col3 as TotalCount,
SIGN(Col1)+SIGN(Col2)+SIGN(Col3) as CommonCount
FROM test.SO1;
```

If you HAVE to use C#, immediate improvement i can suggest is to replace two Parse() calls with one Convert() call. You will also avoid two ToString() calls. Try this:

**REPLACE**

```
nTotalCount += int.Parse(drow[i].ToString());
if (int.Parse(drow[i].ToString()) != 0)
{
    nCommonCount += 1;
}
```

**WITH THIS**

```
var val = Convert.ToInt32(drow[i]);
if(val != 0)
{
    nTotalCount += val;
    nCommonCount++;
}
```

Comment: Performance not affecting on calculating the total and common count values, but at the line where we assign the values to datarow. If i comment those two line, it actually run with quite satisfactory performance

Comment: The difference in c# code mentioned above is giving 40-60% performance increase in my tests. But as you, say, if assigning values is the bottleneck, i could suggest using TPL/Multithreading but then i am not sure it will help you in this case. Can you share more information or show us the code how you are adding columns to the DataTable?

Comment: I have shown in it my question.. I am populating datatable through datareader

Comment: Thanks Rajeev. But what i want to understand is if "Total Count" and "Common Count" columns coming from StoredProc itself or are you using dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn() { ColumnName = "Col1", DataType = typeof(int) }); to add these columns to the DataTable?

Comment: They are coming from stored proc but with '0' as default value

Comment: Thanks Rajeev. I suggest you try the SQL solution once. After that we can try to find other solutions.